# Как проверить множество сайтов на доступность?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Имеется несколько сайтов для получения внешнего ip адресса!

https://api.ipify.org/

http://icanhazip.com/

http://whatismyip.org

http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/

https://ipinfo.io/ip
http://checkip.amazonaws.com

Код для проверки сайта на доступность:

```
public class CheckNet
{
    #region StatusCode
    private static IEnumerable<HttpStatusCode> onlineStatusCodes = new[]
    {
        HttpStatusCode.Accepted,
        HttpStatusCode.Found,
        HttpStatusCode.OK,
    };
    #endregion
    public static bool isOnline(string URL)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.Timeout = 3000;
        try
        {
            WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Затем след:

```
if (CheckNet.isOnline("http://icanhazip.com"))
Console.WriteLine("Сайт ответил, получаем IP адресс:" + (new System.Net.WebClient()).DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com/"));
```

**UPDATE CODE**

```
public static bool CheckURL(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = 15000;
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Получение IP Адресса**

```
public static string GetPublicIP(string url)
{
    try
    {
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new WebClient().DownloadData(url));
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
if (CheckNet.CheckURL("http://icanhazip.com"))
Console.WriteLine("Сайт ответил, получаем IP адресс:" +
CheckNet.GetPublicIP("https://ipinfo.io/ip"));
```

**Проверка с циклами**

```
string[] Links = new string[4] {"https://api.ipify.org/","http://icanhazip.com/","https://ipinfo.io/ip","http://checkip.amazonaws.com/" };
     for (int i = 0; i < Links.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (CheckNet.CheckURL(Links[i]))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Сайт ответил, получаем IP адресс:" + CheckNet.GetPublicIP(Links[i]));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: На другие ошибки, скажем 503 - вы тоже возвращаете true. Зачем?

Comment: Для проверки доступности обычно делают HEAD запрос. Однако, если вы в любом случае планируете запрос на этот ресурс, почему ему бы и не стать проверкой доступности? Зачем лишний запрос?

Comment: И в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: @ArteS так и делать: с помощью запросов к серверу. Желательно как можно более легковесными (например, тот же `HEAD`), чтобы и сервер меньше грузить, и положительный ответ быстрее получать. Если выбор должен быть быстрым, то сканировать сайты можно в фоне, а в основном потоке пользоваться результатами этого сканирования.

Comment: @Regent, Переделал пример под `HEAD`, теперь как проверить множества ссылок на доступность??

Comment: @ArteS всё так же в цикле, проходя по очереди по всем ссылкам.

Comment: @ArteS как вариант, да.

Comment: Не забывайте, что не у всех сайтов одинаковый формат ответа. Узнав, какой из сайтов доступен - вы в общем случае не знаете, как парсить его ответ. Можно убрать из списка те, что отдают не plaintext IP, либо вам придётся вместе с URL хранить метод обработки.

Comment: @Regent, Обновил пост! Правильно я организовал с циклами?

Comment: @ArteS выглядит нормально. Если ещё и работает правильно - совсем хорошо. При создании массива с помощью перечисления, кстати, можно, опустить `new string[4]`: `string[] Links = { ... };`.